# Zabbix Send Message

Tags: action, zabbix

I have a trigger which acts after 3 checks of ping. Interval of checks 3 minutes.
I need to send message like:

```
Host unavailable from [time of first unsuccessfully check]; 
Trigger [time of trigger acts]
```

Which macros i need to use?

Comment: [time of trigger acts] can do with {event.time}. What about time of first unsuccessfully check? Can we do something like {event.time} - 9 minutes?

Comment: Or cheat and just say "Host has been unavailable for 9 minutes as of [time]". You can script notifications of course, so you could do anything you want internally if you script the action, including math. Seems not hardly worth it though.

Comment: I need to do it with script. Any ideas? Can I operate with time in action?

Answer (score 0):

With the comment about scripts I'll offer the following.

Configuration/Actions allow you to specify the content of a message.  That message can be thought of as simply passing parameters to something.  The easy default is that it sends email, but the same parameters can be passed to a script.

Inside the Operations section, you specify the operation as to whom to send (again, think of this as a parameter), and what media type. The user/groups become a parameter as well.

Under Administration, Media types, you can define a media type of "Script". This invokes an external script you write, and passes to it parameters, which by default the first three are the send-to, subject, and message content.  You can (in later Zabbix versions) include other parameters there as well (I do not recall if there is a limit). Before that, I started just passing any data I wanted in a predictable and delimited fashion in the message body, then I parse it out inside my script.

Inside the script itself, you pick up the strings passed in, and do whatever you want.  So if one parameter (subject, explicitly a 4th+ parameter, or buried in a predictable place inside the body of the message) is a time, you can then operate on that time in the language of your choice, replace it, expound upon it, etc.  Then when you have what you want, you send the message from within the script as desired.

Different actions can send using different media types, so you could do a script only for certain types of triggers, based on the conditions written in the action (e.g. a specific trigger name).  So you can use default behavior for some, and custom-write other triggers as desired. The key is to have predictable format in the Config/Action/Triggers, and depend on that format in the Administration/Media types parameters, and inside the script they call. Don't forget to make the script accessible to the zabbix service account and place in the location specified in the zabbix config file. I find it useful to stick with an email-format, then I can "test" my actions by just emailing them, take the resulting email and use it to call my scripts outside of zabbix and ensure they work.

The ability to extend the default alerts by using scripts (and in turn a callable interface to zabbix server itself that can pull additional data from zabbix at script execution) makes alerting a bit arcane, but incredibly powerful. In general you can dynamically include almost anything, including graphs, in the alerts by reacting to the script parameters, and pulling together data to email.